# Create a new command that supports superscript (^) and subscript(_) syntax

Tags: macros, subscripts, superscripts

Consider the integral. `$\int_{0}^{1} x dx$` creates an integral with bounds `0` and `1`.

I defined the `evaluate` command like so:

```
\newcommand{\evaluate}[3]{\left. #1 \right \rvert_{#2}^{#3}}
```

Which I can now use:

```
$\evaluate{\frac{x^2}{2}}{0}{1}$
```

I would like to be able to use this syntax instead:

```
$\evaluate{\frac{x^2}{2}}_{0}^{1}$
```

In the same vein, I could make another command:

```
$\integral{x dx}_{0}^{1}
```

Is that at all possible?

Comment: For `\evaluate` you can just remove the superscript and subscript from the command definition: `\newcommand{\evaluate}[1]{\left. #1 \right \rvert}`. The integral is harder to implement because the super- and subscripts aren't at the end. Might still be possible, but tricky.

Comment: Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a slightly modified version for the `\integral` operator to present the general idea of a way to define such "flexible" scripts.

`\integral` only takes the arguments of the main expression, i.e. the parts which should come after the integral sign with scripts. Those are stored in a temporary command `\temp@expr`. We set the integral sign and then call a helper macro `\integral@` which inspects the next token. If the next token is a subscript character `_`, another helper macro `\integral@sub` is called that gobbles the `_`, reads the following argument (the actual subscript), produces the subscript output, and calls `\integral@` again as a superscript may follow.

The same is done if a superscript character occurs (`\integral@sup`). If the next token isn't either a sub- or superscript character, the integral expression is finished and we can typeset the temporarily stored expression. The inspection via `\@ifnextchar` here allows us to keep the number and order of scripts flexible:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\integral#1#2{\def\temp@expr{#1\,\mathrm d#2}\int\integral@}
\def\integral@{%
    \@ifnextchar{_}{\integral@sub}{%
    \@ifnextchar{^}{\integral@sup}{\temp@expr}}%
}%
\def\integral@sub#1#2{_{#2}\integral@}
\def\integral@sup#1#2{^{#2}\integral@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
    \integral{x^2}{x} \qquad
    \integral{x^2}{x}_a \qquad
    \integral{x^2}{x}^b \qquad
    \integral{x^2}{x}_a^b \qquad
    \integral{x^2}{x}^b_a
\]

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Nice You could mention that if the command is always going to gave limits on the integral, with the subscript first, then there is a shorter solution using `\def`; namely,  `\def\integral#1_#2^#3{\int_{#2}^{#3}#1\,dx}`.  What you have is more flexible, which is better!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a different and much more flexible approach, with a key-value syntax.

The keys for `\integral` are

- `lb` for the lower bound
- `ub` for the upper bound
- `type` for the integral type (default `\int`)
- `along` (a semantic alias for `lb`)
- `domain` (for multiple integrals, it also does `\limits`)
- `style` for overriding the current math style

This way, the same command can be used for much more purposes.

The command `\evaluate` is simpler; it accepts `lb`, `ub` and `size`, the last one for overriding the style chosen by `\left` and `\right`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} % for expl3
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\diff}{} % for differentials
 {
  \mathop{}\!d
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\integral}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { patenaude/integral } { #1 }
  \patenaude_integral:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\evaluate}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { patenaude/evaluate } { #1 }
  \patenaude_evaluate:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { patenaude/integral }
 {
  type .tl_set:N  = \l_patenaude_integral_type_tl,
  type .initial:n = \int,
  lb .tl_set:N    = \l_patenaude_integral_lb_tl,
  ub .tl_set:N    = \l_patenaude_integral_ub_tl,
  along .tl_set:N = \l_patenaude_integral_lb_tl,
  style .tl_set:N = \l_patenaude_integral_style_tl,
  domain .code:n  =
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_patenaude_integral_lb_tl { #1 }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l_patenaude_integral_type_tl { \limits }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \patenaude_integral:n
 {
  \l_patenaude_integral_style_tl % the math style
  \l_patenaude_integral_type_tl % the chosen integral type
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_patenaude_integral_lb_tl % the lower bound or domain
   {
    \c_math_subscript_token { \l_patenaude_integral_lb_tl }
   }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_patenaude_integral_ub_tl % the upper bound
   {
    \c_math_superscript_token { \l_patenaude_integral_ub_tl }
   }
  #1 % the function
 }

\keys_define:nn { patenaude/evaluate }
 {
  lb .tl_set:N = \l_patenaude_evaluate_lb_tl,
  ub .tl_set:N = \l_patenaude_evaluate_ub_tl,
  size .tl_set:N = \l_patenaude_evaluate_size_tl,
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \patenaude_evaluate:n
 {
  \tl_if_empty:NT \l_patenaude_evaluate_size_tl % no chosen size
   {
    \kern-\nulldelimiterspace \left.
   }
  #1 % the function
  \, % some space
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_patenaude_evaluate_size_tl
   {% no chosen size
    \right|
   }
   {
    \l_patenaude_evaluate_size_tl |
   }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_patenaude_evaluate_lb_tl % the lower bound or domain
   {
    \c_math_subscript_token { \l_patenaude_evaluate_lb_tl }
   }
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_patenaude_evaluate_ub_tl % the upper bound
   {
    \c_math_superscript_token { \l_patenaude_evaluate_ub_tl }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\integral{x^2\diff x}             \qquad
\integral[lb=a]{x^2\diff x}       \qquad
\integral[ub=b]{x^2\diff x}       \qquad
\integral[lb=a,ub=b]{x^2\diff x}  \qquad
\integral[ub=b,lb=a]{x^2\diff x}
\]

\[
\integral[type=\iint,domain=\Omega]{xy\diff x\diff y} \qquad
\integral[type=\oint,along=\gamma]{f(z)\diff z}
\]

\[
\integral[style=\textstyle,lb=a,ub=b]{f(x)\diff x}
\]

\[
\evaluate[lb=0,ub=1]{\frac{x^2}{2}}            \qquad
\evaluate[lb=0,ub=1,size=\Big]{\frac{x^2}{2}}  \qquad
\evaluate[lb=0,ub=1]{x}                        \qquad
\evaluate[lb=0,ub=1,size=\big]{x}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]